# starts-with function to filter properties

Tags: xpath

I have an xpath expression that should do the following: checking the naming of @name and checking if the text starts with "machinery" if conditions are fulfilled "something" will been shown.

I have several fields with naming:

- custom.DOC.machinery1
- custom.DOC.machinery2
- custom.DOC.machinery3
- custom.DOC.machinery4
- custom.DOC.machinery5

I need to check if one of above fields (starts with machinery) have text/values who start with "machinery".

So I tried following xpath but it seems not to work:

```
/node/node/node/node[@class = 'InfoType12']/metalist/meta[starts-with(@name,'custom.DOC.machinery') and starts-with(text(),'Machinery')]
```

If I should be able to combine the working xpath (based on your modified xpath) above with following xpath:

```
/node/node/node/node[@class = 'InfoType12']/metalist/meta[@name = 'custom.DOC.machinery1.asterisk' or @name = 'custom.DOC.machinery2.asterisk' or @name = 'custom.DOC.machinery3.asterisk' or @name = 'custom.DOC.machinery4.asterisk' or @name = 'custom.DOC.machinery5.asterisk' and contains(text(),'**')]
```

that would be great.
Now they are in 2 sections, but I think there is maybe a possibility to merge these sections.
Something wrong in my xpath(s)? Other ideas?
I'm using XPath 1.0. **Xml is too large to insert**

```html
<node class="MultiLangRoot" type="MultiLang" primary-aspect-id="131846" primary-aspect-name="en" primary-specific-culture="en-GB" primary-writing-mode="ltr">
    <node class="Layout">
        <title>Declaration_of_conformity_NEW</title>
        </node>
    <node class="MultiLangAspect" type="MultiLang" aspect-id="131846" aspect-name="en" writing-mode="ltr" target-culture="en-GB" character-set="0" htmlhelp-lcid="0x809 English (United Kingdom)">
        <title>English</title>
        <node id="10976987147" xml:space="preserve" aspect-name="en" specific-culture="en-GB" class="Project" type="Unknown" color="-2354116" wf-state="NotReleased" base-id="10976987147" creator="Jesse Victoor" creationtime="2021-06-16T08:42:32" modificator="Jesse Victoor" modificationtime="2021-06-16T08:42:32" releasedby="" releasedate="" releasedate-invariant="" versionnumber="1" tms-state="Neutral" tms-state-displayname="Language-neutral">
            <metalist>
                <meta name="Title">New project</meta>
                <meta name="Document_typeTaxonomyLink" collectable="true">Declaration of Conformity</meta>
                <multi-meta id="3370875395" name="Document_typeTaxonomyLink" collectable="true">
                    <multi-meta-element id="3371659147" base-id="3371659147" value="Declaration of Conformity"/>
                </multi-meta>
            </metalist>
            <title>New project</title>
            <node id="10978966155" format="portrait" class="InfoType12" type="TextNode" color="-65536" wf-state="NotReleased" reuseid="10978974347" base-reuseid="10978974347" base-id="10978966155" chapternumbering="no" showintoc="no" creator="Jesse Victoor" creationtime="2021-06-17T10:30:13" modificator="Jesse Victoor" modificationtime="2021-06-17T10:30:13" releasedby="" releasedate="" releasedate-invariant="" versionnumber="1" content-creator="Jesse Victoor" content-creationtime="17/06/2021 10:28:18" content-creationtime-invariant="2021-06-17T10:28:18" content-modificator="Jesse Victoor" content-modificationtime="30/07/2021 10:23:45" content-modificationtime-invariant="2021-07-30T10:23:45" tms-state="Neutral" tms-state-displayname="Language-neutral" xmlns:st4="http://www.schema.de/2002/ST4/DocuManager" aspect-name="en" specific-culture="en-GB">
                <title>3P663050-1_DOC safety (non PED) - EU in scope of MD</title>
                <metalist>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.affix">* =   ,   , 1, 2, 3, ..., 9</meta>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.EN_standard">EN60335-2-40, </meta>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.machinery1">Machinery 2006/42/EU</meta>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.machinery1.asterik">**</meta>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.machinery2">Low Voltage 2014/35/EU</meta>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.machinery3">Electromagnetic Compatibility 2014/30/EU</meta>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.machinery3.asterik">*</meta>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.manufacturer">Daikin Europe N.V.</meta>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.sign.left">Yes</meta>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.sign.right">No</meta>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.standalone.sign.left">No</meta>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.standalone.sign.right">Yes</meta>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.TCF">Yes</meta>
                    <meta name="custom.DOC.units1">Units</meta>
                    <meta name="custom.first.flow">Left page</meta>
                    <meta name="meta.Pub.Format" sysValue="portrait">Portrait</meta>
                    <meta name="Title">3P663050-1_DOC safety (non PED) - EU in scope of MD</meta>
                </metalist>
                <content>
                    <modref src="b1f75d7b-ada4-4088-ba31-fd7a1bb91b24"/>
                    <modref src="c8943c42-7c0f-4e77-806f-2872da269a4d"/>
                    <modref src="7300b119-c8ea-4945-ba51-84d50302a575"/>
                    <modref src="7658bf10-d95c-4cd9-b906-101f5e148949"/>
                    <modref src="f603d081-6e60-48ba-b112-6d907865cc49"/>
                    <modref src="d2115d02-441c-4ec1-b82d-2210a4a62d08"/>
                    <modref src="f75ff48b-8f83-495c-972e-a2af20cd033c"/>
                    <modref src="e927b213-cf96-4fff-b61d-d9b27a7a0ec4"/>
                    <modref src="d2338324-ba6d-4b20-862c-10efcb28fb7e"/>
                    <modref src="1dc84a97-13ba-4eed-840b-e0a1fe1360fa"/>
                </content>
                <node id="10979452683" class="TextModule2" type="TextModule" color="-1969921" wf-state="NotReleased" base-id="10979452683" chapternumbering="yes" showintoc="yes" creator="Jesse Victoor" creationtime="2021-06-17T15:37:52" modificator="Jesse Victoor" modificationtime="2021-06-17T15:37:52" releasedby="" releasedate="" releasedate-invariant="" versionnumber="1" content-creator="Jesse Victoor" content-creationtime="17/06/2021 15:37:52" content-creationtime-invariant="2021-06-17T15:37:52" content-modificator="Administrator" content-modificationtime="29/04/2016 02:25:51" content-modificationtime-invariant="2016-04-29T02:25:51" tms-state="Neutral" tms-state-displayname="Language-neutral" linkid="f75ff48b-8f83-495c-972e-a2af20cd033c" xmlns:st4="http://www.schema.de/2002/ST4/DocuManager" aspect-name="en" specific-culture="en-GB">
                    <title>DENV is authorized to compiled TCF table</title>
                    <metalist>
                        <meta name="Title">DENV is authorized to compiled TCF table</meta>
                    </metalist>
                    <content>


                        <table-container type="noframe">

                            <table hsdl-cm="0.40 6.77 0.40 6.98 0.40 6.97 0.40 6.38" type="scaled">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>01**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>02**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>03**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>04**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>05**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>06**</b>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. is authorised to compile the Technical Construction File.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. hat die Berechtigung die Technische Konstruktionsakte zusammenzustellen.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. est autorisé à compiler le Dossier de Construction Technique.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. is bevoegd om het Technisch Constructiedossier samen te stellen.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. está autorizado a compilar el Archivo de Construcción Técnica.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. è autorizzata a redigere il File Tecnico di Costruzione.</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>07**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>08**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>09**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>10**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>11**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>12**</b>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Η Daikin Europe N.V. είναι εξουσιοδοτημένη να συντάξει τον Τεχνικό φάκελο κατασκευής.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">A Daikin Europe N.V. está autorizada a compilar a documentação técnica de fabrico.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Компания Daikin Europe N.V. уполномочена составить Комплект технической документации.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. er autoriseret til at udarbejde de tekniske konstruktionsdata.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. är bemyndigade att sammanställa den tekniska konstruktionsfilen.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. har tillatelse til å kompilere den Tekniske konstruksjonsfilen.</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>13**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>14**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>15**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>16**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>17**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>18**</b>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. on valtuutettu laatimaan Teknisen asiakirjan.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Společnost Daikin Europe N.V. má oprávnění ke kompilaci souboru technické konstrukce.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. je ovlašten za izradu Datoteke o tehničkoj konstrukciji.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">A Daikin Europe N.V. jogosult a műszaki konstrukciós dokumentáció összeállítására.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. ma upoważnienie do zbierania i opracowywania dokumentacji konstrukcyjnej.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. este autorizat să compileze Dosarul tehnic de construcţie.</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>19**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>20**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>21**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>22**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>23**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>24**</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>25**</b>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. je pooblaščen za sestavo datoteke s tehnično mapo.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. on volitatud koostama tehnilist dokumentatsiooni.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. е оторизирана да състави Акта за техническа конструкция.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. yra įgaliota sudaryti šį techninės konstrukcijos failą.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. ir autorizēts sastādīt tehnisko dokumentāciju.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Spoločnosť Daikin Europe N.V. je oprávnená vytvoriť súbor technickej konštrukcie.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. Teknik Yapı Dosyasını derlemeye yetkilidir.</p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </table-container>
                    </content>
                </node>
                <node id="10979459083" class="TextModule2" type="TextModule" color="-1969921" wf-state="NotReleased" base-id="10979459083" chapternumbering="yes" showintoc="yes" creator="Jesse Victoor" creationtime="2021-06-17T15:37:52" modificator="Jesse Victoor" modificationtime="2021-06-17T15:37:52" releasedby="" releasedate="" releasedate-invariant="" versionnumber="1" content-creator="Jesse Victoor" content-creationtime="17/06/2021 15:37:52" content-creationtime-invariant="2021-06-17T15:37:52" content-modificator="Administrator" content-modificationtime="29/04/2016 02:25:51" content-modificationtime-invariant="2016-04-29T02:25:51" tms-state="Neutral" tms-state-displayname="Language-neutral" linkid="e927b213-cf96-4fff-b61d-d9b27a7a0ec4" xmlns:st4="http://www.schema.de/2002/ST4/DocuManager" aspect-name="en" specific-culture="en-GB">
                    <title>DENV is authorized to compiled TCF table</title>
                    <metalist>
                        <meta name="Title">DENV is authorized to compiled TCF table</meta>
                    </metalist>
                    <content>


                        <table-container type="noframe">

                            <table hsdl-cm="0.40 0.40 6.67 0.40 6.88 0.40 6.87 0.40 6.28" type="scaled">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b/>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>01***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>02***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>03***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>04***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>05***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>06***</b>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. is authorised to compile the Technical Construction File.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. hat die Berechtigung die Technische Konstruktionsakte zusammenzustellen.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. est autorisé à compiler le Dossier de Construction Technique.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. is bevoegd om het Technisch Constructiedossier samen te stellen.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. está autorizado a compilar el Archivo de Construcción Técnica.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. è autorizzata a redigere il File Tecnico di Costruzione.</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>07***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>08***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>09***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>10***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>11***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>12***</b>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Η Daikin Europe N.V. είναι εξουσιοδοτημένη να συντάξει τον Τεχνικό φάκελο κατασκευής.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">A Daikin Europe N.V. está autorizada a compilar a documentação técnica de fabrico.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Компания Daikin Europe N.V. уполномочена составить Комплект технической документации.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. er autoriseret til at udarbejde de tekniske konstruktionsdata.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. är bemyndigade att sammanställa den tekniska konstruktionsfilen.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. har tillatelse til å kompilere den Tekniske konstruksjonsfilen.</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>13***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>14***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>15***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>16***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>17***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>18***</b>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. on valtuutettu laatimaan Teknisen asiakirjan.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Společnost Daikin Europe N.V. má oprávnění ke kompilaci souboru technické konstrukce.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. je ovlašten za izradu Datoteke o tehničkoj konstrukciji.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">A Daikin Europe N.V. jogosult a műszaki konstrukciós dokumentáció összeállítására.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. ma upoważnienie do zbierania i opracowywania dokumentacji konstrukcyjnej.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. este autorizat să compileze Dosarul tehnic de construcţie.</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>19***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>20***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>21***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>22***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>23***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>24***</b>
                                            </p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">
                                                <b>25***</b>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. je pooblaščen za sestavo datoteke s tehnično mapo.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. on volitatud koostama tehnilist dokumentatsiooni.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. е оторизирана да състави Акта за техническа конструкция.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. yra įgaliota sudaryti šį techninės konstrukcijos failą.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. ir autorizēts sastādīt tehnisko dokumentāciju.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Spoločnosť Daikin Europe N.V. je oprávnená vytvoriť súbor technickej konštrukcie.</p>
                                            <p type="p_table_l">Daikin Europe N.V. Teknik Yapı Dosyasını derlemeye yetkilidir.</p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </table-container>

                    </content>
                </node>
                <linklist>
                    <link name="TextModuleLink" id="10978969484" target="EU-declaration of conformity table" source="3P663050-1_DOC safety (non PED) - EU in scope of MD" target-id="10976335115" target-base-id="10976335115" source-id="10978966155" label="b1f75d7b-ada4-4088-ba31-fd7a1bb91b24" color="-3283201" external="0"/>
                    <link name="TextModuleLink" id="10978970508" target="Declares under its sole responsibility that the PRODUCTS table" source="3P663050-1_DOC safety (non PED) - EU in scope of MD" target-id="10976381579" target-base-id="10976381579" source-id="10978966155" label="c8943c42-7c0f-4e77-806f-2872da269a4d" color="-3283201" external="0"/>
                    <link name="TextModuleLink" id="10978971276" target="Are in conformity with the following directive(s) or regulation(s), provided that the products" source="3P663050-1_DOC safety (non PED) - EU in scope of MD" target-id="10976429963" target-base-id="10976429963" source-id="10978966155" label="7300b119-c8ea-4945-ba51-84d50302a575" color="-3283201" external="0"/>
                    <link name="TextModuleLink" id="10978972044" target="as amended." source="3P663050-1_DOC safety (non PED) - EU in scope of MD" target-id="10976569099" target-base-id="10976569099" source-id="10978966155" label="7658bf10-d95c-4cd9-b906-101f5e148949" color="-3283201" external="0"/>
                    <link name="TextModuleLink" id="10978972812" target="following the provisions of:" source="3P663050-1_DOC safety (non PED) - EU in scope of MD" target-id="10976643851" target-base-id="10976643851" source-id="10978966155" label="f603d081-6e60-48ba-b112-6d907865cc49" color="-3283201" external="0"/>
                    <link name="TextModuleLink" id="10978973580" target="Certificate A-B-C" source="3P663050-1_DOC safety (non PED) - EU in scope of MD" target-id="10976733835" target-base-id="10976733835" source-id="10978966155" label="d2115d02-441c-4ec1-b82d-2210a4a62d08" color="-3283201" external="0"/>
                    <link name="TextModuleLink" id="10979511564" target="DENV is authorized to compiled TCF table" source="3P663050-1_DOC safety (non PED) - EU in scope of MD" target-id="10979452683" target-base-id="10979452683" source-id="10978966155" label="f75ff48b-8f83-495c-972e-a2af20cd033c" color="-3283201" external="0"/>
                    <link name="TextModuleLink" id="11292616844" target="DENV is authorized to compiled TCF table" source="3P663050-1_DOC safety (non PED) - EU in scope of MD" target-id="10979459083" target-base-id="10979459083" source-id="10978966155" label="e927b213-cf96-4fff-b61d-d9b27a7a0ec4" color="-3283201" external="0"/>
                    <link name="TextModuleLink" id="11292618380" target="DICZ is authorized to compiled TCF table" source="3P663050-1_DOC safety (non PED) - EU in scope of MD" target-id="10979503627" target-base-id="10979503627" source-id="10978966155" label="d2338324-ba6d-4b20-862c-10efcb28fb7e" color="-3283201" external="0"/>
                    <link name="TextModuleLink" id="11292617612" target="DICZ is authorized to compiled TCF table" source="3P663050-1_DOC safety (non PED) - EU in scope of MD" target-id="10979493387" target-base-id="10979493387" source-id="10978966155" label="1dc84a97-13ba-4eed-840b-e0a1fe1360fa" color="-3283201" external="0"/>
                </linklist>
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>
</node>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample XML  ? And also, which version of xpath are you using ?

Comment: How about using https://pastebin.com/ or cut down on the XML but give a sample that is representative of the structure you want to match with the xpath

Comment: That would be simple with XPath 2

Comment: First xpaths seems to works fine. The second one does not work because the name ends in `.asterik` but your xpath uses `.asterisk` (*note the `s` before the `k` in the xpath*)

Comment: you're right, fault in .asterisk. I solved but same result. I will consult other resources too